Streamlined tagging for Mochizuki
For better or worse, there is a number of questions at MO on Mochizuki's stuff.  I noticed that some of the questions have the tag "abc-conjecture" while others don't have this tag.  Should Mochizuki-related questions be listed under the abc-conjecture tag, or not?

If a question is related to the abc conjecture, including attempts at proof, then the tag is appropriate.  For example, the recent questions are related.

Mochizuki has published lots of work. Not all of it is abc stuff. For example, is there an anabelian geometry tag?

Yes.
